# ProGuard doesn't obfuscates Serializable class completely

Tags: android, proguard, serializable

In my app I have some classes, which implements `Serializable/Externalizable` interface.

After decompilation classes, which implements `Serializable` or `Externalizable` have obfuscated names like `a, b` and so on, but names of fields and methods remain the same. Bodies of methods are obfuscated too.

The same problem affects `Enum`'s, which has methods and fields (except their own instances).

My `proguard-rules.pro` file is next

```
-optimizationpasses 5

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}

-dontwarn android.support.**

-keepclasseswithmembernames, includedescriptorclasses class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keep public class android.support.v7.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.widget.** { *; }
-keep public class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider {
    public <init>(android.context.Context);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    !private <fields>;
    !private <methods>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}

-keepclassmembers, allowoptimization enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

One more detail: before addition of `-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {...}` part my app failed on deserialization step. I tried [examples](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#serializable) from ProGuard's site, but only last one works.

So what can I do in this case? Is there configuration to obfuscate classes, which implements `Serializable/Externalizable` completely?

Answer (score 0):

The line with `-keepclassmembers` indeed preserves the names of most fields and methods. As explained in the ProGuard manual > Examples > [Processing serializable classes](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#serializable), you may need this line if you serialize classes that don't have `serialVersionUID` fields. If you add these fields, you can probably use a less conservative configuration that obfuscates more methods.

Comment: shame on me, I'll try it now and answer as soon as possible and thank you a lot)